# What is the best tool to extract artwork from .ipa files (iOS7)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

Since Xcode 5 introduces asset catalogs, the old appcrush/pngcrush methods no longer work for extracting artwork from ipa files.

Does anyone know the best tool for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This app should work
http://www.pragmaticcode.com/crunch/
Have not tried it, but seeing people posting about it

Comment: Whoops, sorry if this was OT.  Thanks for the answer this is exactly what i was looking for :)